# git update-index assume-unchanged error: assume-unchanged: does not exist and --remove not passed

Tags: git

I am trying to tell Git to ignore changes I make to a properties file so that I don't accidentally commit it to my git repository. I am using:

git update-index assume-unchanged [file]

Which gives the output:

error: assume-unchanged: does not exist and --remove not passed
fatal: Unable to process path assume-unchanged

I don't know what this error message means and Google appears to have drawn a blank. The [file] mentioned above is versioned in the repository and has filesystem (not added to staging area) changes.

How can I get Git to ignore filesystem changes to my file (so that "git add ." will not add it to the staging area)?

Thanks!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Maybe it's an accidental error when you wrote the question, but I think the "--" is missing in front of the argument.

Does `git update-index --assume-unchanged [file]` work?

Comment: For me this meant that my web software had re-written the command from "--assume-unchanged" to "-assume-unchanged" (with a large hyphen to start).  The fix was to remove the junk initial hyphen and replace with "--" like "--assume-unchanged"